# Find $ \lim_{ \epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{R^n-(R-\epsilon)^n} \int_{R-\epsilon\le \|x\| \le R} e^{-\frac{\|x-\mu\|^2}{2}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

How to find the following limit
\begin{align}
 \lim_{ \epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{R^n-(R-\epsilon)^n} \int_{R-\epsilon\le \|x\| \le R} e^{-\frac{\|x-\mu\|^2}{2}} dx.
\end{align}

For the case of $n=1, $ I was able to compute this and the limit is given by  $e^{-\frac{(\mu -R)^2}{2}}+e^{-\frac{(\mu +R)^2}{2}}$. However, not sure how to do it in general.

**Reasoning that I had (which is wrong)**
Intuitively for a very small epsilon 
\begin{align}
\int_{R-\epsilon\le \|x\| \le R} e^{-\frac{\|x-\mu\|^2}{2}} dx&= e^{-\frac{\|R-\mu\|^2}{2}}  \int_{R-\epsilon\le \|x\| \le R}  dx\\
&= e^{-\frac{\|R-\mu\|^2}{2}}  V_n  (R^n-(R-\epsilon)^n),
\end{align}
where $V_n$ is the volume of a unit ball.  So, my guess for the limit was
\begin{align}
e^{-\frac{\|R-\mu\|^2}{2}}  V_n .
\end{align}

However, this does not appear to be correct as it does not agree with the $n=1$ case.  As Did pointed out my assumption is not correct.

This question looks possibly related to 
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{Vol(B_c(\epsilon))} \int_{B_c(\epsilon)} f(x) dx ,
\end{align}
where  $B_c(\epsilon)$ is a ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $c$. The difference is that we are looking at the annulus instead of a ball.

Comment: "Intuitively for a very small epsilon" The identity just after that, is everything but intuitive, and in fact most probably wrong except when $\mu=0$.

Comment: @Did You, see I thought that when $\epsilon \to 0$ then $\| x \| =R$. Thanks for pointing out that this is not so.

Comment: @Did Could you suggest how to proceed with finding this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's evaluate the limit. Note that it's an indeterminate form

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{p(\epsilon)}{q(\epsilon)}$$
where
$$\begin{split}
q(\epsilon)&\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}R^n-(R-\epsilon)^n\\
&=R^n-(R^n-nR^{n-1}\epsilon +O(\epsilon^2))\\
&=nR^{n-1}\epsilon +O(\epsilon^2)
\end{split}$$

$$\begin{split}p(\epsilon)&\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\int_{R-\epsilon\le \|x\| \le R} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\|x-\mu\|^2}{2}} dx\\
&=\int_{R-\epsilon}^R\int_{S_{n-1}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\|r\hat{x}_{\Omega}-\mu\|^2}{2}}r^{n-1}\mathrm{d}\Omega\,\mathrm{d}r\text{.}\end{split}$$

($\hat{x}_{\Omega}$ is the direction vector of $x$, and $\Omega$ ranges over the unit sphere $S_{n-1}$.) Let $$f(r)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\int_{S_{n-1}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\|r\hat{x}_{\Omega}-\mu\|^2}{2}}r^{n-1}\mathrm{d}\Omega\text{.}$$ Then

$$\begin{split}p(\epsilon)&=\int_{R-\epsilon}^Rf(r)\,\mathrm{d}r\\
&=\int_{0}^{\epsilon}f(R-s)\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\epsilon f(R)+O(\epsilon^2)\text{.}
\end{split}$$

Therefore
$$\begin{split}\frac{p(\epsilon)}{q(\epsilon)}&=\frac{\epsilon f(R) +O(\epsilon^2)}{\epsilon nR^{n-1}+O(\epsilon^2)}\\
&=\frac{f(R)}{nR^{n-1}}+O(\epsilon)\text{.}
\end{split}$$

so the limit in question is equal to
$$\begin{split}
 \lim_{ \epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{R^n-(R-\epsilon)^n} \int_{R-\epsilon\le \|x\| \le R} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\|x-\mu\|^2}{2}} dx
&=\frac{f(R)}{nR^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{nR^{n-1}}\int_{S_{n-1}}\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac{1}{2}\|R\hat{x}_{\Omega}-\mu\|^2}R^{n-1}\mathrm{d}\Omega\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac{1}{2}R^2-\tfrac{1}{2}\mu^2}}{n}\int_{S_{n-1}}\mathrm{e}^{\hat{x}_{\Omega}\cdot\mu R}\mathrm{d}\Omega
\end{split}$$

In turn, the remaining integral is [expressible](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E2) in terms of a modified Bessel function:
$$\int_{S_{n-1}}\mathrm{e}^{\hat{x}_{\Omega}\cdot a}\mathrm{d}\Omega =(\tfrac{a}{2})^{1-n/2}S_{n-1}\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2})I_{n/2-1}(a)\text{.}$$
(Here $S_{n-1}$ is the content of the unit $(n-1)$-sphere.) Therefore
$$\lim_{ \epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{R^n-(R-\epsilon)^n} \int_{R-\epsilon\le \|x\| \le R} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\|x-\mu\|^2}{2}} dx
=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac{1}{2}R^2-\tfrac{1}{2}\mu^2}}{n}(\tfrac{\mu R}{2})^{1-n/2}S_{n-1}\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2})I_{n/2-1}(\mu R)\text{.}
$$

Comment: Can you explain how you changed the limits of integration?

Comment: The integral can be thought of as an integral over the sphere $\|x\|=r$ followed by integration of $r$ from $R-\epsilon$ to $R$. The limit is the indeterminate form $0/0$, so it can be evaluated by taking derivatives of the numerator and denominator. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the numerator is left with an integral over $\|x\|=R$.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you. But I can not follow this step. Could you put in more detail?

Comment: I think there is a mistake. I am assuming that by content of a sphere you mean that $S_{n-1}=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$. Suppose we want to compute your example for $n=1$. Then, we get   \begin{align}  e^{-\frac{R^2+x^2}{2}} (\mu R/2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} S_{0} I_{-1/2}(\mu R) \end{align}. Now using that $S_{0}=2$  and $I_{-1/2} (x)= sqrt(\frac{2}{ \pi x}) \cosh(x)$ we have that \begin{align} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} ( e^{-\frac{(\mu-R)^2}{2}} +  e^{-\frac{(\mu+R)^2}{2}})\end{align}  However, the solution should not contain $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.

Comment: Missed a $\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2})$ when adapting the integral expression, sorry.

Comment: Can you also put more details on the Lopital rule  on FTC? For example, I am not clear of what function are you taking the derivative.

Comment: I added more detail about the indeterminate form.